# Как в PHP проставить \ перед всеми функциями?

Tags: php, easy-coding-standard

В проекте для единообразия было решено использовать слеш перед функциями, ака \array_filter, \in_array

Используется https://github.com/symplify/easy-coding-standard и symfony

Comment: что-то кажется мне что читаемости кода это не добавит

Comment: @teran это называется: когда есть много свободного времени и нечем заняться))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я допускаю некоторый буст в скорости, когда имена функций ищутся только в строго указанном неймспейсе, но сдается мне что это происходит только на этапе интерпретации, а в опкоде хранится уже полный вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в ecs.php

```
return static function (ContainerConfigurator $containerConfigurator): void {
    $services = $containerConfigurator->services();
    $services->set(\PhpCsFixer\Fixer\FunctionNotation\NativeFunctionInvocationFixer::class)->call('configure', [[
        'include' => [\PhpCsFixer\Fixer\FunctionNotation\NativeFunctionInvocationFixer::SET_INTERNAL],
    ]]);
};
```